# Regular expression to match function name and all arguments in Python

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have a string such as the following:

```
"func(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, ..., argn)"
```

EDIT: This function is not in some particular language. It just has this format. If it makes it easier, don't think of it as a function call, just a string.

I want to write a regular expression to match the function and **each** of the arguments. I am writing this in Python. The desired output of this is:

```
{"function" : "func", "arg" : ["arg1", "arg2", ... , "argn"]}
```

EDIT: While the arguments could be function calls, I can easily recursively try to match them with the same regular expression once I create one that works. By this I mean I can recurse on the function with each of the arguments. But this is not really relevant. I am **not** trying to create an interpreter, just something to recognize the arguments.

Here is my attempt at this:

```
import re
s = "func(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, argn)"
m = re.match(r"(?P<function>\w+)\s?\((?P<args>(?P<arg>\w+(,\s?)?)+)\)", s)
print m.groupdict()
```

And here is the output:

```
{'function': 'func', 'args': 'arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, argn', 'arg': 'argn'}
```

The function matches just fine, and so does the argument set. However, I can't seem to match the individual arguments. Is this a problem with my regex, or a limitation of Python regular expression matching?

EDIT2: I am aware that I can now split the arguments using the following code:

```
d["arg"] = d["args"].split(", ")
```

But I was wondering if I could do the whole job with regular expressions. In particular, I am wondering why "arg" is matched to only the last argument.

EDIT3: I guess I am (1) hoping to figure out why Python only matches the last argument every time, and (2) whether I can do Scheme-style pattern-matching in Python. Or if there is something just as intuitive in Python as Scheme-style pattern matching. I looked at the ast module, and its syntax is prohibitively complex.

Comment: Is this function call in some particular language? You shouldn't use a regular expression to parse a language for which a correct/complete parser already exists...

Comment: You can't do this with regular expressions (assuming you want to match the individual arguments, which themselves could be function calls). You need an actual parser. If you insist on writing your own, then read this: http://effbot.org/zone/simple-iterator-parser.htm

Comment: You might want to check out [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) if you are planning on doing something more complex.

Comment: "I can easily recursively try to match [the arguments] with the same regex"  - No, you can't easily do that. Regular expressions don't work that way.

Comment: @Eduardo, yes we know it can theoretically be done, but it really shouldn't be done.

Comment: @Wes: I know it should not be done. Regexes are evil *precisely* because they are *not* regular expressions. What I meant is "please someone elaborate on the difference between regexes and regular expressions".

Comment: Umm... what *is* the difference between regex and regular expression?

Comment: As far as I can tell the difference is that originally regular expressions did not have many of the features that "regexes" have like backreferences, etc...

Comment: @Wes: And those "features" make regexes technically more powerful than true regular expressions, i.e., there are things that can be parsed / pattern-matched using regexes that cannot be parsex using regular expressions. (Although no one in their sane mind would use those "features".)

Comment: Anyone creating something with regexes that is complex enough to match a language with multiple types of nestable brackets (and strings!) that are going to be handled right… anyone doing that is evil and mad. Use a proper parser and save the head-pounding complexity for somewhere where it is actually justified.

Comment: @EduardoLeón StackOverflow only has a regex tag, not a regular expression tag (as far as I could see). I changed regex to regular expression in the problem description.

Comment: @BlackSheep: Because Stack Overflow is a programming Q&A site, not a computer science Q&A site. As Donal Fellows said, the best solution in this case is to implement your own recursive descent or recursive ascent parser. The former are easier to implement, the latter allow for more flexibility.

Comment: So, by create a parser you mean go through the string token by token?

Comment: @BlackSheep: Well, you certainly need a lexer (whose only task is to split the string into tokens) and the parser proper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you're 90% there, why not just swap the `arg` and `args` groupings and do:

```
import re

fn_match = re.match(r"(?P<function>\w+)\s?\((?P<arg>(?P<args>\w+(,\s?)?)+)\)", s)
fn_dict = fn_match.groupdict()
del fn_dict['args']
fn_dict['arg'] = [arg.strip() for arg in fn_dict['arg'].split(',')]
```

Comment: I'm trying to capture the whole thing as a regex. Is that not possible?

Comment: Not to get the resultant list of args that you want.  Why use only a swiss army knife when you have a whole toolbox?

Answer (score 9):

Regular expressions cannot parse complex programming languages.

If you're just trying to parse Python, I suggest taking a look at the [ast](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html) module, which will parse it for you.

Comment: I'm not trying to parse Python, just capture a very specific syntax. From the little I read, it seems that the ast module is (1) specific to Python, and (2) is pretty complex for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code that would be needed in order to get `ast` to return the parameters of a function definition in Python?

Comment: With the help of [this](https://suhas.org/function-call-ast-python/) I was able to figure it out using `ast`. For Python, you can do `parsed = ast.parse("def foo(a, b, c):\n\tpass")` followed by `result = {"function": parsed.body[0].name, "args": [ast_arg.arg for ast_arg in parsed.body[0].args.args]}`

Answer (score 1):

To answer the last part of your question: No. Python does not have anything similar to Scheme's "match", nor does it have pattern matching like ML/Haskell. The closest thing it has is the ability to destructure things like this

```
>>> (a, [b, c, (d, e)]) = (1, [9, 4, (45, 8)])
>>> e
8
```

And to extract the head and tail of a list (in Python 3.x) like this...

```
>>> head, *tail = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> tail
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

There are some modules floating around that do real pattern matching in python though, but I can't vouch for their quality.

If I had to do it, I would implement it a bit differently -- maybe have the ability to input a type and optional arguments (e.g. length, or exact content) and a function to call if it matches, so like match([list, length=3, check=(3, str), func]) and that would match (list _ _ somestr) and call func with somestr in scope, and you could also add more patterns.