# Regexp for python-like function parameters parsing

Tags: c++, regex

I am trying to make use [questions like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10164137/regular-expression-to-match-function-name-and-all-arguments-in-python) to devise a regexp that will match and give a **function name** and **all parameters** in a very simplified Python-like syntax like the following:

```
mycall(x, y, hello)
```

with the desired results:

- function name: `mycall`
- parameter 0: `x`
- parameter 1: `y`
- parameter 2: `hello`

Of course it should also match `noparams()`, and any number of parameters. As for my simplifications, I just need parameters names, I don't allow default parameters or something different from a list of comma separated names.

My tries with variants of `"(\\s*)([A-Za-z0-9_])+\\(\\)"` just to match a function name string with spaces at the beginning are failing, with this code:

```
    std::regex fnregexp(s);

    std::smatch pieces_match;

    if (std::regex_match(q, pieces_match, fnregexp))
    {
        std::cout << ">>>> '" << q << "'" << std::endl;

        for (size_t i = 0; i < pieces_match.size(); ++i)
        {
            std::ssub_match sub_match = pieces_match[i];
            std::string piece = sub_match.str();
            std::cout << "  submatch " << i << ": '" << piece << "'" << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

I have the following output for `"     hello()"`:

```
>>>> '     hello()'
  submatch 0: '     hello()'
  submatch 1: '     '
  submatch 2: 'o'
```

With this very basic syntax, is it possible to find name of the function and its parameters?

Cheers!

Comment: Not sure what exactly you want to parse: Function declarations like `def foo(param):` in Python or calls to that function?

Comment: A string that matches a Python-like function header, I can also omit `def`.

Comment: Can your input contain more than one function ?

Comment: No, just one function, nothing fancy for now (for complicated things I'd go with Boost Spirit, probably).

Comment: If there is no noise with the function, the simplest regex you could use is `\w+`. First match would be the function name, each other match would be the arguments

Comment: If you want to be a bit safer, use this one : `\w+(?=\s*[\(,\)])`. However it should do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for the conformance check:

```
^\\s*[A-Za-z_]\\w* *\\( *(?:[A-Za-z_]\\w* *(?:, *[A-Za-z_]\\w* *)*)?\\)$
```

and if it's ok use this for extracting the parts of signature:

```
\\w+
```

the first submatch is the function name, the others are parameters.

EDIT: The correct synthax for Python is `[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*`

Comment: You can remove the lookahead, and it will do the same ;) Edit : Oh, you just did ^^

Comment: Yes, because originally the answer did not provide the first check, so I thought other kinds of checking were necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Matching simple function declarations with regex is feasable. For more complicated things you have exactly the right idea in going with a real parser like Boost Spirit.

The bug in your question is a wrong closing parens in the regex. Compare:

```
"(\\s*)([A-Za-z0-9_])+\\(\\)" // yours
"(\\s*)([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\\(\\)" // correct
```

The capture group in your version captures only a single character. Because of how the regex engine works it is the last one matched: the *o*. The correct version includes the *+* in the group and captures *hello* as expected.