# NonRegex way of extracting unknown number of strings into a tuple in Python

Tags: python, string, tuples

Hi I have a line of code I'm reading from a file like this:

```
x = funct(arg1, arg2, arg3, ... , argn)
```

The number of `args`, and their names are unknown. They are comma separated and all the arguments are enclosed in a set of braces `()`.

In my python script I'd like to extract the argument names and form a `tuple` like so:

```
Line = "x = mathfunction(op, mul, div, add)"
ArgsTuple = ExtractArgs(Line)
print ArgsTuple
```

Desired output:

`["op", "mul", "div", "add"]`

Where `ExtractArgs` is the magic function that processes the line into the `tuple`.

I feel this should be pretty easy, but I just can't see how.

Comment: You could do it using eval().

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match function name and all arguments in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10164137/regular-expression-to-match-function-name-and-all-arguments-in-python)

Comment: You can google about using `*args` and `**kwargs` with Python functions. That might help you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `split()` the `string` multiple times to get the result you want, for example:

```
Line = "x = mathfunction(op, mul, div, add)"
print Line.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(', ')
```

output:

```
['op', 'mul', 'div', 'add']
```

EDIT:

You can type cast it to `tuple()` if you want, as the following:

```
tuple(Line.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(', '))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this:

```
def ExtractArgs(text):
  return list(i for i in text.split('(')[1][:-1].split(','))

line = "x = mathfunction(op, mul, div, add)"
ArgsTuple = ExtractArgs(line)
print ArgsTuple
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to extracting the data with string manipulation methods, you can parse the line into an abstract syntax tree, and extract the names from the Call node:

```
import ast

class ArgumentExtractor(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def visit_Call(self, node):
        self.args = [name.id for name in node.args]

def get_names(line):
    node = ast.parse(line)
    a = ArgumentExtractor()
    a.visit(node)
    return a.args

line = "x = mathfunction(op, mul, div, add)"
names = get_names(line)
print(names)
```

Result:

```
['op', 'mul', 'div', 'add']
```

One benefit this has is that it will only accept lines that are actually valid Python. Suppose you're getting these lines from an untrustworthy source and you're not certain about whether it's junk or not. If your line is something like `"f(x,y,z)!)@)#)"`, perhaps you'd prefer for your program to crash here instead of handing you a tuple of values that may gum things up later in a harder-to-diagnose spot. Compare `ExtractArgs` from the other answer:

```
>>> s = "f(x,y,z)!)@)#)"
>>> ExtractArgs(s)
['x', 'y', 'z)!)@)#']
```

And Moe's expression:

```
>>> s = "f(x,y,z)!)@)#)"
>>> s.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(', ')
['x,y,z']
```

... To `get_names`:

```
>>> s = "f(x,y,z)!)@)#)"
>>> get_names(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in get_names
  File "C:\Programming\Python 3.5\lib\ast.py", line 35, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    f(x,y,z)!)@)#)
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Now you can set up a try-except to handle SyntaxErrors in case of bad lines.